# How to get contents of array with name '' (empty string)

Tags: typescript

Here is the where I get the values:

```
registerUser(localUser: LocalUser) {
    this.registrationService.registerUser(this.localUser)
        .subscribe(
            resp => this.statusMessage = resp,
            error => {
                if(error._body != undefined) {
                    let arr = error._body.modelState;
                    var errorObject  = JSON.parse(error._body);
                    }
            },
            () => this.completeRegister());
}
```

The following is an error object I return from an http request to register a new client using asp.net and webapi 2.  As you can see Model state is an object that contains an array.

this is the json return from webapi which I JSON.parse into errorObject:

```
    "{   
         "message": "The request is invalid.",   
         "modelState": {
                 "": [
                        "Name jbaird@test.com is already taken.",
                        "Email 'jbaird@test.com' is already taken."
                     ]
         } 
      }"
```

[image]

I have tried absolutely everything today that I can think of, using typescript, to get to those array values, all for naught.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I updated the question to show how I'm getting the value.  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the array is the value of a property named as an empty string, you could access it like so

```
errorObject.modelState['']
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I missed that part :-/

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would never have arrived at that by myself.